# SpringMVC: Multi viewresolver

Tags: java, html, css, spring-mvc

I created `InternalResourceViewResolver` for mapping URL in `.java` files. Now, I also want to give style my html pages with `.css` files. But, when The request comes with .css URL, control goes to `.java` files to search mapping for the given URL. 
So, Is it possible to have another ViewResolver particularly for all css/js files?

Here is my code for `sdnext-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.visionet" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.visionet.model.School</value>
                <value>com.visionet.model.Country</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

here comes my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done in the configuration for the dispatcher servlet.  Within this file you can place a `<resources/>` tag that denotes the directly containing the client side resources.  This directory will then be excluded from being handled by the dispatcher servlet, allowing static resources such as CSS and JS to be served without interference by the dispatcher.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/kmb385/toThought/blob/github_master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml) of the tag in use:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/ by efficiently serving
up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

This XML snippet would be placed in your `/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml` file.  It would map every request starting with `/resources/` to the `/resources/` directory located within the root of your web application.  The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources) also provides a nice write up for how the resources tag works.

Comment: Sorry, its not working for me. I've added complete code above for `sdnext-servlet.xml` file

When i run the code, I got this error

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 22 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 63; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.`

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?  The resources tag was introduced in 3.0.4 or later.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a resources root which does not use the resolver.  In the same spot that you defined the jspViewResolver bean, add the following.

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Create a resources directory at the same level as your WEB-INF directory, like this.

```
resources
     - css
     - images
     - 
WEB-INF
     - ...
```

You would reference your css like this, anything under /resources does not use the view resolver.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/styles.css" />
```